# Reusing HTML code blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In one of the page I am working on, I have to reuse a html block of code again and again.
This is a legacy application and the whole html, js code is very old.
The HTML block in question is more than 200 lines of code. 
Current approach that I am using is to convert the block in javascript and store the whole block in a variable and then return it

```
function getItemBlock() { 
var strItemBlock=""; 
    strItemBlock += "<div class=\"itemblock newitem\" >";
    strItemBlock += "<h5>Item <span class=\"itemnum\"><\/span> <button   lass=\"btnDeleteItem btn\">Delete Item<\/button><\/h5>";
   strItemBlock += "<div class=\"row\">";
   strItemBlock += "<div class=\"col\">";
   strItemBlock += "<\/div>";
   return strItemBlock;
}
```

Another approach that I can use is to create whole structure using javascript createElement which would be more hectic and slower in performance.
What options do I have, I am looking for only client side options using javascript.

Comment: I would suggest using cloneNode to just clone the structure.

Comment: That means I have to provide the code block on the page somewhere.

Comment: "slower in performance" are you sure about that?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can clone elements that only exists in memory as well.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js ?

Comment: Yes because , it would involve creating all the elements manually rather than just inserting HTML code.The sample code block is only a portion of the entire block

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would use a function rather than just declaring a variable that contains the string, unless you intend to pass parameters to the function to alter the string

Comment: Generally using createElement, fragments etc. would be faster and more readable than just sticking an entire string of HTML somewhere, it still has to be parsed. Faster to write maybe

Comment: @str : I have kept open the option to use a templating library like mustache. but still trying to see if some other solutions are there

Comment: @kevin - i want to pass parameters to create dynamic Id's and other things

Comment: @adeneo I will look into createElement and fragment and evaluate their performance..i am fairly new to javascript so was not sure

Comment: Having a function use `createElement` and partnering it up with `.cloneNode()` would be the fastest way for you if HTML block doesn't change at all.

Comment: Thanks @LaughDonor, for the comment.. I do have a different variations of the block but in different pages. so when I thought about the whole application I came with my first approach, but it looks ugly to me and not easy to maintain.

Comment: Here is a performance test of innerHTMl vs createElement http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test

Comment: @budding_fed The context of your HTML Block changing is independent of the other pages you have. So on the same page, if you're using the same block, then using `document.createElement()` and `element.cloneNode()` would be the fastest. Generating the code to create the element is up to you and the page it's on. There's so many JSPerf links out there, [here's another](http://jsperf.com/string-vs-createelement/3).

Comment: If it is easier for you to make it as a string, go ahead transform it into a DOM element ***once***, and then clone it however many times you need for the rest of that page.

Comment: Thanks again @LaughDonor, I was aware of the approach you suggested but you did convince me to try it. Will try to implement it.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo for suggesting the same approach in your earlier comments

Answer (score 1):

I usually just create an array like so:

```
function getItemBlock() { 
  var strItemBlock=['<div class="itemblock newitem" >',
              '<h5>Item <span class="itemnum"><\/span>',                                       
              '<button class=\"btnDeleteItem btn\">Delete Item<\/button>', 
              '<\/h5>',
              '<div class=\"row\">',
              '<div class=\"col\">',
              '<\/div>']
  return strItemBlock.join('\n');
}

 $('#wrapper').append(getItemBlock());
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hayoxona/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use the approach the user LaughDonor suggested, here are the comments

@budding_fed The context of your HTML Block changing is independent of the other pages you have. So on the same page, if you're using the same block, then using document.createElement() and element.cloneNode() would be the fastest. Generating the code to create the element is up to you and the page it's on. There's so many JSPerf links out there, here's another. –  LaughDonor 20 mins ago

If it is easier for you to make it as a string, go ahead transform it into a DOM element once, and then clone it however many times you need for the rest of that page. –  LaughDonor 18 mins ago